# Module throws name error when imported from package

Tags: python, web2py, python-module

I'm trying to import a module that contains a single line: `import logging`, into my web2py project. When I try to import the module from within a package called `mymodules`, I get a `<type 'exceptions.NameError'> name 'logging' is not defined error`, but When I take the module out of the package and import it directly, it works fine.

mymodule.py:

```
import logging
```

Importing it from top-level modules directory:
`import mymodule` - works fine

Importing from a package:
`from mymodules import mymodule` - get the name error

There's nothing wrong with the package - I have other modules in there that I import with no problem. Don't have a clue as to why this is happening.

Answer (score 1):

Once you import mymodule, you then have to refer to `mymodule.logging` rather than just `logging`.

Comment: Anthony that doesnt make sense- logging is part of the Python Standard Library- i should be able to import it into any module I want. And besides, I'm not even referring to anything yet, I'm just importing the module and already getting the error.

Comment: No, the problem is not with importing logging within mymodule.py. The problem is that once you import mymodule in your app, logging is in the mymodule namespace, so you have to refer to it as `mymodule.logging`, not just `logging`. The error you are getting does not appear to be the result of the import statement, but the result of a reference to `logging` at some point. Apparently, wherever you are referring to `logging`, it is not available in that namespace. Where exactly is the `from mymodules import mymodule` statement? Can you show the full traceback?

Comment: Also, note that you should not include the .py extension in your import statements -- it should just be `from mymodules import mymodule`.

Comment: FYI, I've have done exactly as you describe -- mymodule.py module inside a mymodules package, and mymodule.py simply imports logging. When I do `from mymodules import mymodule` in my app, I don't get any error.

Comment: Anthony- I wasn't making any reference in my code, but it's possible some old .pyc files were- (see my answer). My test was literally just importing the module, which is why I was so stumped. I'm still not clear on why top-level modules would ever need namespace qualifications, but I'll deal with that when I need to.. Anyway, thanks for taking the time.

Answer (score 0):

First off,  you dont need to add the file extension `.py` to your import statement. So it should be:

```
import mymodule
mymodule.logging.info("Just some info")
```

Anthony is correct though, if you want to be able to use logging from there, you would have to call it via `mymodule.logging` You could also use a wildcard import but you just need to be a little careful of what you then import in mymodule.

```
from mymodule import *
#now you can use logging directly
logging.info("Just some info")
```

Comment: MattoTodd- Why would standard library modules would ever need to be namespaced? They don't belong to the imported module in question?

Answer (score 0):

This was happening because of some old .pyc files that were still in the package- they must have been causing the bad logging references. Once I cleared them my problem was solved. :S